# How to implement interceptor in sails js

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

I am new for sails and angular.

Currently we are working on sails.
I am looking for how to use interceptor in sails.
In java we use to implements interceptor to intercept the request but I want to know how to implements the interceptor in sails.
I also search it on web but i did not get much about it.

Does anyone know how to implements it in sails?
Is their any built in npm or if not what we do to achieve it?
Are their is any other way that I miss in sails documentation?

Comment: `middleware` should solve your use case. Check http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/middleware

Comment: yes that work for mi..thank u..